# How to define default file with caddy?

Tags: caddy

Simple one but I can't figure out,

How do I choose the name of the default file served on caddy configuration ?

For example, I want to go on my domain http://www.whatever.com/ and I want Caddy to automatically serve http://www.whatever.com/foo.html instead of index.php.

I tried with redir and rewrite, but nothing works.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score -1):

Find out ! To define a file (or files) that the server has to try, the directive is try_files.

```
Example : www.whatever.com:80 {
    root * /app
    encode gzip
    file_server
    try_files {path} foo.html
}
```